# How to restrict a user to access only specific folders

Tags: linux, ssh, chroot

I have an Ubuntu server installed and I need to give access to my client's sites hosted on my server. There are currently 2 sites, which means 2 folders.

I was able to create a user with the command:

```
adduser user
```

However, I cannot find a way how to restrict this user to view only specific folders. If you tell me at least how to restrict a user to only one folder on your server that would be great!

I googled a bit and I found something about chroot. If I understood correctly, this will literally create a new root for the user which ultimately means restricting certain folders. However, I am no linux expert and didn't manage to use it.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: this is a great question for server fault or superuser BTW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[chmod](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) allows you to set permissions on folders and you can use the old unix group method of securing files and folders.  If you want more fine grained control you will need to install the [ACL](http://www.beginlinux.com/server_training/server-managment-topics/1038-ubuntu-804-access-control-lists) package.